# Display name of category in td

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display subcategory in `td` but I like the result with some formatting. The output is going on weight column so need help to improve code. How can I display one by one `product_name`? for each loop create the second `td` & it will go to the weigh column. I want to display this `product_name` with auto-increment `$i`

**Excepted result:**

```
  product_name
  1)face wash
  2)face cream
```

my result:

```
face wash face cream
```

**Blade file code:**

```
          <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Order summary</strong></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td><strong>Product Name</strong></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><strong>Weight</strong></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
                            <td class="text-right"><strong>Price</strong></td>
                            <td class="text-right"><strong>SubTotal</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <!-- foreach ($order->lineItems as $line) or some such thing here -->
                        <tr>
                            <?php 
                            $subcategory=explode(',', $bill->name_of_subcategory);
                            $weight=explode(',', $bill->weight);
                            $orders_qty=explode(',', $bill->orders_qty);
                            $price=explode(',', $bill->price);
                            $orders_subtotal=explode(',', $bill->orders_subtotal);
                            ?>
                            <td><?php
                            $subcategory=explode(',', $bill->name_of_subcategory); 
                            for($i=0;$i<count($subcategory);$i++)
                            {
                              echo $subcategory[$i];
                            }
                            ?></td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ $bill->weight }}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ $bill->orders_qty }}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ $bill->price }}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ $bill->orders_subtotal }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="thick-line"></td>
                            <td class="thick-line"></td>
                            <td class="thick-line"></td>
                            <td class="thick-line text-center"><strong>Subtotal</strong></td>
                            <td class="thick-line text-right">{{ $bill->total }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                            <td class="no-line text-center"><strong>SGST</strong></td>
                            <td class="no-line text-right">{{ $bill->sgst }}%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                            <td class="no-line text-center"><strong>CGST</strong></td>
                            <td class="no-line text-right">{{ $bill->cgst }}%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                            <td class="no-line text-center"><strong>IGST</strong></td>
                            <td class="no-line text-right">{{ $bill->igst }}%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                            <td class="no-line"></td>
                            <td class="no-line text-center"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                            <td class="no-line text-right">{{ $bill->grand_total }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what is your question? How to apply formatting to the subcategory?

Answer (score 0):

you should create a `<td>` foreach result.

```php
<table> 
    <?php

        $subcategory=explode(',', $bill->name_of_subcategory);

        for($i=0;$i<count($subcategory);$i++)
        {
            echo "<tr><td>".$subcategory[$i]."</td></tr>";
        }
    ?>  
</table>
```

Comment: I assume you have a table coded right? I updated the answer.

Comment: can i share whole table ?

Comment: Not getting result

Comment: Do you want to show results in columns (side by side) or each result in one line?

Comment: one after another

Comment: Ok I updated the answer to list a line foreach result.

Comment: sir i also want to display weight,qty ,price & subtotal in same format

Comment: how can i arrange?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <?php
    $subcategory=explode(',', $bill->name_of_subcategory); 
    foreach($subcategory as $row){ ?>
        <td>{{$row}}</td>
    <?php } ?>
</tr>
</table>
```